# Match length of two Python lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy, signal-processing

I have two Python lists of different length. One may assume that one of the lists is multiple times larger than the other one.

Both lists contain the same physical data but captured with different sample rates.

My goal is to downsample the larger signal such that it has exactly as much data points as the smaller one.

I came up with the following code which basically does the job but is neither very Pythonic nor capable of handling very large lists in a performant way:

```
import math

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,4.5,6.9]

if len(a) > len(b):
    div = int(math.floor(len(a)/len(b)))
    a = a[::div]
    diff = len(a)-len(b)
    a = a[:-diff]
else:
    div = int(math.floor(len(b)/len(a)))
    b = b[::div]
    diff = len(b)-len(a)
    b = b[:-diff]
print a
print b
```

I would appreciated if more experienced Python users could elaborate alternative ways to solve this task.

Any answer or comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that by advancing just the floor of the division there can be a large accumulated error for longer lists! E.g., if one list has 7 elements, and the other has 4, you will take just the first four elements, instead of every other one.

Comment: @tobias_k That's true. In my case however, one list might have 80000 elements and the other one just 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shortened version of the code (not necessarily better performance):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,4.5,6.9]
order = 0  # To determine a and b.

if len(b) > len(a):
    a, b = b, a  # swap the values so that 'a' is always larger.
    order = 1

div = len(a) / len(b)  # In Python2, this already gives the floor.
a = a[::div][:len(b)]

if order:
    print b
    print a
else:
    print a
    print b
```

Since you're ultimately discarding some of the latter elements of the larger list, an explicit `for` loop may increase performance, as then you don't have to "jump" to the values which will be discarded:

```
new_a = []
jump = len(b)
index = 0
for i in range(jump):
    new_a.append(a[index])
    index += jump
a = new_a
```

Comment: You can further simplify this to `a = a[::div][:len(b)]`. No need for the new length of `a` if we just count from the beginning. Also much clearer what's the intent IMHO.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks! I've added it. What do you think about my other code?

Comment: Note, however, the OP's original code does not swap the variables... Code further down the line might have to be adapted, or you should swap again.

Comment: @tobias_k Pardon? I don't get it.

Comment: OP only "downsamples" the larger list, whereas your code downsamples one of the last, and may or may not swap the lists. After your code ran, it is impossible to say which list was `a` and which was `b` before its execution.

Comment: @SamChats tobias_k is right. The swapping falsifies the final printouts (b is shown instead of a and vice versa) and should be removed.

Comment: @Rickson So should I create new lists for modification? Without swapping, the code length would increase.

Comment: @SamChats Yes, I would suggest to remove the swapping. You may also use the numpy arrays instead of the lists as mentioned by user2699. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

First off, for performance you should be using `numpy`.  The questions been tagged with `numpy`, so maybe you already are, and didn't show it, but in any case the lists can be converted to numpy arrays with

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
```

Indexing is the same. 
It's possible to use `len` on arrays, but `array.shape` is more general, giving the following (very similar) code.

```
 a[::a.shape[0] // b.shape[0]]
```

Performance wise, this should give a large boost in speed for most data.
Testing with a much larger a and b array (10e6, and 1e6 elements respectively), shows that numpy can give a large increase in performance.

```
a = np.ones(10000000)
b = np.ones(1000000)

%timeit a[::a.shape[0] // b.shape[0]]  # Numpy arrays
1000000 loops, best of 3: 348 ns per loop

a = list(a); 
b = list(b);
%timeit a[::len(a) // len(b)]    # Plain old python lists
1000000 loops, best of 3: 29.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're iterating over the list, you could use a generator so you don't have to copy the whole thing to memory.

```
from __future__ import division

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,4.5,6.9]

def zip_downsample(a, b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        b, a = a, b  # make b the longer list
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        yield a[i], b[i * len(b) // len(a)]

for z in zip_downsample(a, b):
    print z
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
#b = [1,4.5,6.9]

a, b = zip(*zip(a, b))

# a = [1, 2, 3]
# b = [1, 4.5, 6.9]
```

The inner zip combines the lists into pars, discarding the excess items from the larger list, returning something like `[(1, 1), (2, 4.5), (3, 6.9)]`. The outer zip then performs the inverse of this (since we unpack with the * operator), but since we have discarded the excess with the first zip, the lists should be the same size. This returns as `[a, b]` so we then unpack to the respective variables (`a, b = ...`).

See
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip for more info on zip and using it as it's own inverse

Comment: The expected output for a is `[1, 4, 7]`, b does not need to be computed