# Match length of arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, comparison

There are some examples online how to subtract values from longer arrays so it matches the length of a shorter one ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965444/match-length-of-two-python-lists)). However, the order of values in longer array changes. Is there a way to subtract values from the end of longer array?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 5, 8, 2, 7, 3, 5, 9, 4, 10]
```

*some code*

Output:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 5, 8, 2, 7]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work, no matter the size or order of the arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 5, 8, 2, 7, 3, 5, 9, 4, 10]

m = min(len(a), len(b))
a = a[:m]
b = b[:m]
```

Comment: Now. this. is. art. Honestly one of the most elegant code segments I have seen in a while.

Answer (score 3):

Just get the list slice from index 0 to `len(a)-1`:

```
b = b[:len(a)]
```

Output:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [1, 5, 8, 2, 7, 3, 5, 9, 4, 10]
>>> b = b[:len(a)]
>>> b
[1, 5, 8, 2, 7]
```

In case `a` is bigger than `b`:

```
>>> a = [1, 5, 8, 2, 7, 3, 5, 9, 4, 10]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = b[:len(a)]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Please note how there's no error in case the ending index of the slice is greater than the size of the list.

So, if you don't know what is the shorter array, just perform the slice on both of them:

```
b = b[:len(a)]
a = a[:len(b)]
```

and only the bigger one will be "shortened".

Comment: What if `a` is bigger than `b`?

Comment: @JammyDodger In that case `b` is left unchanged. See my edit

Comment: A general solution that works in both cases is likely what is required, which is what both of the other answers show.

Comment: @JammyDodger but it does work in both cases! Slicing with an _out of bounds_ max index doesn't raise an error. It just returns elements until they are available. There's no need to calculate the minimum length.

Answer (score 1):

Cut any amount of lists to equal lengths:

```
def even_length(*args):
    target_size = min(map(len, args))
    return tuple(l[:target_size] for l in args)
```

Usage:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 5, 8, 2, 7, 3, 5, 9, 4, 10]

a, b = even_length(a, b)
print(a, b)
```

Of course, you can also pass a `list` or `tuple` of lists, if working with individual lists is getting inconvenient.

```
lists = (a, b, c, d)
lists = even_length(*lists)
```